# Auto submit is not working with form post to centinel

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, forms, http-post

I am having problem posting a form to Sentinel payment gateway. The code below is working fine if I place submit button on the form and user has to click it to post to action url. But I want to post automatically after a 2 second delay, the code does not work. I have checked that action url is correctly set in both the cases. Can anybody point what am I doing wrong here?

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.CartAuthenticateModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/BlankLayout.cshtml";
}
type="text/javascript"></script>

<form id="frmLaunchACS" name="frmLaunchACS" method="Post" action="@Model.Centinel_ACSURL">
    <br>

    <br>
    <div style="text-align: center; margin: 20px;">
        <h3>Please wait...while redirecting to payment gateway</h3>
        <input type=hidden name="PaReq" value="@Model.CentinelPayload"/>
        <input type=hidden name="TermUrl" value="@Model.CentinelTermURL"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="MD" value="@Model.Centinel_TransactionId"/>
        <input id="submit-form" type="submit" />        
    </div>   
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            var auto = setTimeout(function() { autoRefresh(); }, 100);

            function submitform() {
                document.forms["frmLaunchACS"].submit();
            }

            function autoRefresh() {
                clearTimeout(auto);
                auto = setTimeout(function() {
                    submitform();
                    autoRefresh();
                }, 2000);
            }
        }

</script>
```

Comment: your code seems to be redirecting fine after 2sec delay.

Comment: Yes, after 2 secs it posts form to action url but it is rejected from Sentinel. If I click submit button, it works fine. Don't know why is it happening?

Comment: thats weird! Any permision or something issue at Sentinel end ?